# Parsing simple molecule names with Attoparsec

Tags: parsing, haskell, attoparsec

I find it extremely difficult to learn how to use Attoparsec, because the documentation is really just an API documentation and there are basically no tutorials around (except the one from FPComplete). If you know other places where I can learn Attoparsec, that'd be great.

I have to parse simple molecule names, in the following format: `NaCl`, `CO2`, `H2O`, `HCN`, `H2O2`.
An **element** name is an uppercase letter optionally followed by a lowercase one (I'm not considering those elements with a symbol longer than 2 characters).
An element can be followed by a **number** (that would be the subscript in a formula).

New version (thanks to Mark's and Tarmil's suggestions), which compiles but does not parse:

```
module Chem
    where

import Data.Text (Text, pack)
import Control.Applicative ((<*>), (<$>))
import Data.Attoparsec.Text

data Element = Element String Int deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)
type Molecule = [Element]

parseString :: String -> Result Molecule
parseString = parse (many' parseElement) . pack

parseElement :: Parser Element
parseElement = do
    el <- (++) <$> pClass "A-Z" <*> option "" (pClass "a-z")
    n  <- option 1 decimal
    return $ Element el n

pClass :: String -> Parser String
pClass cls = (\c -> [c]) <$> satisfy (inClass cls)
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

**EDIT**: I managed to get it running. Basically, a `Partial` continuation was returned, and to finish the parsing it's necessary to feed the parser with an empty bytestring. So the correct `parseString` would be:

```
parseString = flip feed empty . parse (many' parseElement) . pack
```

where `empty` is `Data.Text.empty`. However, since I don't need incremental parsing there is the useful function `parseOnly`, which does not wait for more input and returns an `Either`.

With that in mind, I rewrote the code like this (it works now):

```
module Chem
    where

import Data.Text (Text, pack)
import Control.Applicative ((<*>), (<$>))
import Data.Attoparsec.Text

data Element = Element String Int deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)
type Molecule = [Element]

parseString :: String -> Either String Molecule
parseString = parseOnly (many' parseElement) . pack

parseElement :: Parser Element
parseElement = do
    el <- (++) <$> pClass "A-Z" <*> option "" (pClass "a-z")
    n  <- option 1 decimal
    return $ Element el n

pClass :: String -> Parser String
pClass cls = (\c -> [c]) <$> satisfy (inClass cls)
```

Comment: `Information` is supposed to be subscript? I'm not really good at chemistry, but if there is no subscript, 1 is implied. So, what do you think about something like `data Element = Element String Int` (if there is no number you can use `1` in constructor), and then you can write `type Molecule = [Element]`. And your parser will be something like `Parser Molecule`...

Comment: @Mark: Yes, it would be `1`. I didn't consider things this way, it seems very reasonable!

Comment: Check out the functions `parseOnly` and `parseTest`. Unless you are trying to parse something huge or streaming `parseOnly` is the way to go. `parseTest` is good for checking how your parser will work and helps you detect the `Partial` thing if you do want to eventually use `parse` which is almost never. `parseWith` is best for huge streaming things where you want to supply more data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems in the letters parsing part:

- `inClass` is not a parser, it is a function that is meant to be passed to `satisfy`.
- `<*>` has type `Parser (a -> b) -> Parser a -> Parser b`, so the parser on the left should return a function. Typically, it is used like this:

  ```
  pf <$> p1 <*> p2 <*> ... <*> pn
  ```

  where `pf` is a function with `n` arguments.

So here you probably want something like this:

```
-- parse a character in the given class, and transform it to a single-char string
pClass cls = (\c -> [c]) <$> satisfy (inClass cls)

-- ...
    el <- ((++) <$> pClass "A-Z" <*> pClass "a-z") <|> pClass "A-Z"
-- ...
```

I think this would be enhanced by using `option`, instead of duplicating the `A-Z` parser:

```
    el <- (++) <$> pClass "A-Z" <*> option "" (pClass "a-z")
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I see now the errors. Following your suggestion I edited the code, but now the function `parseString` always returns a `Partial _` match. If I remove `many'` it matches only the first element obviously. Can you please have a look at the new code? Thanks!